# LINQPad: Attempting to use assembly that uses [DllImport] to access C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, linqpad

I added MyAssembly.dll as an additional reference to my query, and that works fine: I am able to use various classes from it with no trouble.

One of the methods for one of the classes in MyAssembly.dll references another dll (Wrapper.dll).  Wrapper.dll uses [DllImport] to access functionality in a C++ dll (C.dll):

> [DllImport("C.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint ="CPlusPlusFunction")]
>   internal static extern UInt32 _CPlusPlusFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string file_path);

While this method works perfectly fine when executed from MyApp.exe that references MyAssembly.dll (which references Wrapper.dll, which references C.dll), in LINQPad I can't get it to work.

If I only add a reference for MyAssembly.dll and attempt to run the method, I get:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'C.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

If I add an Additional Reference for just Wrapper.dll, I get the same error.

If I add an Additional Reference for both Wrapper.dll AND C.dll, I get:

> Metadata file 'C.dll' could not be opened -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

If I add an Additional Reference for just C.dll I get the same error.

Any idea on how I can get this to work in LINQPad like it does in MyApp.exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it the exact same way, you'll have to copy it in the same directory as the EXE so Windows can find it.  The LINQPad EXE in this case.  C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4 by default.  Or any directory that's on the PATH, c:\windows\syswow64 is the infamous choice.  Best not to do that.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that did the trick.

It turns out you can also put the .dll in the same directory as the .linq script.

Comment: Windows can also find a DLL if it is in the current working directory (Environment.CurrentDirectory).  Not unlikely to work when LINQPad changes the directory to the script.  That tends to be a bit hit and miss though.